# Android login at once

Tags: android

How do I code for login in some app in android that I do not need to login in it again next time I open the application ?
I tried a lot, but no success. If possible please provide me code.

Comment: could you please include what you have tried and what errors you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

In my app I created a base class for all my activities which checks in oncreate if the user is logged in with shared preferences. If not I show the login screen and continue my app after a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

If this login is local:
First time when you login,

```
Editor editor= YourSharedPreference.edit();
editor.put(nameOfAccount,name);
editor.put(passwordOfAccount,password);
editor.commit();
```

Then every time you open the APP,

```
if(YourSharedPreference.contain(nameOfAccount)&&YourSharedPreference.contain(passwordOfAccount))
{//do not need login}
else
{//do login thing}
```

Comment: Please never store passwords in plaintext! Use a token like a session cookie or something like that!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way it to store it in the shared preferences.

Basicaly you request a [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) then you can [get string value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from it (load).
Using the a SharedPreferences.Editor you can [put string value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) into it (save).

Checking if the value is set (null) will tell you if the user already logged in your app or not.

Here an exemple:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_PREF", 0);
   String login = settings.getString("login", null);
   String password = settings.getString("password", null);

   if(login == null || password == null){
       // Do stuff for login user
   }else{
       // Do stuff for not logged user
   }

}

public void saveLogin(String password, String login){
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_PREF", 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor loginEditor = settings.edit();
     loginEditor.putString("login", login);
     loginEditor.putString("password", login);
     loginEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Please never store passwords in plaintext! Use a token like a session cookie or something like that, the rest of your answer looks fine.

Comment: @rekire I'm just 100% agree with you. But I wanted the keep the answer as simple as possible.